# For the extreme newbie, how do I have a background image for my ui in QT creator

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt, qt-creator, mel

I am trying to build UIs in QT Creator that look like my UIs in MEL but I am having a hard time since I don't know C++ and I am very new to QT Creator. I read something about changing style sheets but I never got the resource root to work. I looked at the help section in Creator but for some reason I don't have the "Edit Resources" button. I want to do something like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JhDZbzA2ObM. Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: I did, but this was  a really long time ago and I don't remember what I did. If you need help on it I can try to find the files when I get home from work.

Comment: Oh, I used the `pyrcc` command to convert a resource file into a Python file. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use QtDesigner to draw your gui and you can set the stylesheet of every widget. The resources are manipolated from QtDesigner, not QtCreator. Eventually you can run the designer from inside Qt creator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short intro on Qt resource system [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html). And here is some info on [stylesheets](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html). Should be enough to kickstart manual stylesheet implementation. :)